# How to align the radio buttons in hyperref form?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyperref, forms

I am trying to create a formular, this is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{%
\leavevmode #2 #1%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
Choose wisely:\\ \\
\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=pokemon,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{Charmander is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very good.}{=charmander}\\
\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=pokemon,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{Bulbausaur is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very good.}{=bulbasaur}\\
\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=pokemon,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{Squirtle is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very good.}{=squirtle}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

And this is what i get:
[image: result of my mwe]

How can i align the "Charmander" to the "very" in the second line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the choice menu with items in a regular `itemize`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{%
  \leavevmode #2 #1%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
Choose wisely:
\begin{itemize}
  \item[{\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=pokemon,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=charmander}}]
  Charmander is very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
  very very very very very very very very very very very good.

  \item[{\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=pokemon,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=bulbasaur}}]
  Bulbausaur is very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
  very very very very very very very very very very very good.

  \item[{\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=pokemon,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{=squirtle}}]
  Squirtle is very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
  very very very very very very very very very very very good.
\end{itemize}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

To hide the optional argument of `\ChoiceMenu`, wrap it in a braced group `{`...`}`. The advantage of the above method is that list items will wrap across the page boundary.

Answer (score 5):

With a `\parbox`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{%
\makebox[2.5em][l]{#2}\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
Choose wisely:\\ \\
\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=pokemon,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{Charmander is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very good.}{=charmander}\\
\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=pokemon,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{Bulbausaur is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very good.}{=bulbasaur}\\
\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=pokemon,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{Squirtle is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very good.}{=squirtle}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```